# Make a blocking call to a function in Node.js required in this case?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am starting to learn node.js. I am stuck with a problem here. I am calling a weather service which returns a JSON(url below).

http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_key/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json

I want to display the results from the api on an HTML page.

I have written the following code(getInfo module) to retrieve and return the JSON.

```
var fbResponse; 

module.exports = function (url) {

var http=require('http');


http.get(url, function(res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        fbResponse = JSON.parse(body);  
        console.log("Got response: ", fbResponse.response);


    });

}).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: ", e);
});


return fbResponse;
};
```

So to use this module I created a test.js file as follows:

```
var relay = require('./getInfo');
var url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_key/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json';
var response;
var x=relay(url);

console.log (x);
```

Output is as follows:

```
undefined                //  console.log(x) from test.js
Got response:  { version: '0.1',
  termsofService: 'http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html',
  features: { conditions: 1 } }
```

The console output in the test code runs first with no data in it. The HTTP get competes later and displays the actual output I need.

How can I modify the test code to make a blocking call such that var x  in the test code actually have the JSON output instead of undefined?

Can I achieve the desired result without a blocking call to the getInfo module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know, node is asynchronous, so the callback of `http.get` and `res.on('end', ..` will fire after `relay` function is executed and it is returned. So normally you can't return the result from it.

You have a couple of choices:

- Pass a callback to `relay` and use that:

  ```
  module.exports = function (url, cb) {
      http.get(url, function(res) {

          var body = '';
          res.on('data', function(chunk) {
              body += chunk;
          });

          res.on('end', function() {
              cb(null, JSON.parse(body));
          });

      }).on('error', cb);
  };
  ```

  Then use it like this:

  ```
  var relay = require('./getInfo');
  relay(url, function (err, x) {
      if (err) {
          console.error('oohh i got a error: ', err)    
      }
      console.log('oohh i got a response: ', x)    
  });
  ```
- Use promises. This is almost same as passing callbacks. A little less lightweight, but when combining different asynchronous operations, you will understand how awesome they are. For just one asynchronous call there might not be any difference. Here I use [`q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). You can also use [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) which is way more performant but lacks some of the sugar of q. You can read [this article](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2013/03/30/callbacks-are-imperative-promises-are-functional-nodes-biggest-missed-opportunity/) to understand why promises are cleaner than callbacks in some cases.

  ```
  module.exports = function (url) {
      var deferred = Q.defer();
      http.get(url, function(res) {
          var body = '';
          res.on('data', function(chunk) {
              body += chunk;
          });

          res.on('end', function() {
              deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(body));
          });

      }).on('error', function(e) {
          deferred.reject(e);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
  };



  var relay = require('./getInfo');
  relay(url).then(function responseHandler(x) {
      console.log('my awesome response')
  }, function errorHandler(err) {
      console.error('got an error', err);
  });
  ```
- Use generators. It is part of Ecmascript 6 specification it only exists in node v0.11.x and later. But it would be almost what you want.

  With that past promise example we can do this:

  ```
  Q.async(function *() {
      var relay = require('./getInfo');
      var x = yield relay(url);
      console.log('my awesome response', x)
  });
  ```

  This is almost what you want. You can also achieve it using the callback solution with [`co library`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/co):

  ```
  co(function *() {
      var relay = require('./getInfo');
      var x = yield relay.bind(null, url);
      console.log('my awesome response', x);
  });
  ```

  You can also use [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/) in above example which is almost a similar tool like generators.

  If you want to use bleeding edge Javascript, you can use [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) instead of generators with promises.

Comment: people like you make Stackoverflow a nice wiki. a knowledge base with all the experience poured into neat answers. Thank you!

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in a callback instead:

```
var http = require('http');

module.exports = function(url, cb) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            var resp, err;
            try {
              resp = JSON.parse(body);
            } catch (ex) {
              err = ex;
            }
            cb(err, resp);
        });

    }).on('error', function(e) {
          console.log("Got error: ", e);
          cb(e);
    });
};
```

Then use it like:

```
var relay = require('./getInfo');
var url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_key/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json';
var response;
relay(url, function(err, resp) {
  if (err) throw err; // TODO: handle better
  console.dir(resp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a callback in your module function to return the result.

```
module.exports = function (url, onsuccess) {
    ...

    res.on('end', function() {
        fbResponse = JSON.parse(body);
        if(onsuccess){
            onsuccess(null, fbResponse);
        }
```

Then in your caller code:

```
relay(url, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

Another option is to use `httpsync` module which provides **synchronous** apis for the same functionality that 'http' module provides. But in node js programming, you should always **avoid synchronous calls**.